# ESLlint Resolve error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined from using "config" npm depencency

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, config, eslint

I recently started receiving the below error in Intellij

```
ESLint: 
Resolve error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Levi\workspace\webpack.config.js:35:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.exports.resolve (C:\Users\Levi\workspace\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-webpack\index.js:69:27)
    at v2 (C:\Users\Levi\workspace\application\node_modules\eslint-module-utils\resolve.js:117:23)
(import/no-unresolved)
```

This is the portion of the webpack.config.js mentioned in the error

```
const config = require('config');
const webpackConfig = removeEmpty({
 output: {
        publicPath: ifNotProd(`${config.app.baseUrl}/`),  <-----line 35 from the error
```

At first, I thought, it was caused by the latest update to Intellij IDEA 2020.2.  To verify that I downgraded the version of Intellij.  The error did resolve itself for a short time, but then returned even after being on the previous version of Intellij.  Like something was cached but once a specific sort of rebuild of my Intellij environment occurred the error resurfaced.

My main concern is that whatever sort of magic Intellij does to resolve dependencies is erroring in most, but not all of my files.

Sometimes it looks like this:

[image: File with import errors]

Other times it looks like this:

[image: File with ESLint error banner]

If I disable all of ESLint the errors go away, as you would expect.  I tried to ignore just the webpack.config.js file but that did not appear to resolve the issue.

I've considered semantic versions of dependencies changing as I use ^version syntax.

My questions are:

1. What is ESLint doing that it's running into issues, is it "building" something that allows it to do loose type checking that is now failing?
2. Has anyone else run across this sort of issue with the `config` npm module?

If you need more information let me know and I will try to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step to debugging this I would replace `removeEmpty` with `Object.freeze` to see if you can find what is deleting `baseUrl`.

If you catch it needing to change something else first, just move `Object.freeze` to after that and catch the next mutation until you find the one your interested in.

Comment: First, I did try your suggestion to see if it gave me any more information.  I did not see anything in addition to the errors above.
Second, I'm not sure I've explain the issue correctly.  The application runs.  The config dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) runs like it should at runtime.  ESLint appears to errors during its execution ("build"?, not sure of the term).  It feels like ESLint is trying to validate that the config:
`const config = require('config');` contains the `app` property, which it does not. `app` is from the json file it should load. Does that make sense?

Comment: To me this looks like `plugin-eslint-import` is crashing when it tries to read the config. I don’t have any more ideas, maybe open a bug ticket on GitHub for that project.